# Using setInterval in promise chain which uses Redux-Thunk async action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a rather obscure problem and it may indeed arise from my own doing so feel free to point it out if that is the case.

I have a chain of promises, which I need access to intermediate values for subsequent API calls. Once the promises are all resolved, I then execute an API call that makes use of the various intermediate return values.

Finally, based on the results of that call I then make a final call to an API. However, the results of this call are used to update a Redux State and therefore are done using Redux Thunk as the middleware to facilitate async actions.

The challenge arises in that I then need to poll a database at a set interval to check if the Redux API call has carried out the work requested of it (This worked involved placing some long running tasks on a Redis task queue and then having the queue worker update a database once the task is complete).

When the database confirms that it has indeed been updated with the completed task status, I want to clear the setIntervalId. I have simplified the code to that shown below. The issue is that the execution does not wait for the Redux async action to be completed. So it executes the action then goes straight on to carry out the 'if' check before the Redux action is cmplete. Therefore the if is never true and the polling continues indefinitely.

I do not know how to ensure the Redux Action is complete before code continues. I have trimmed the code down to get the logic in place without overcrowding this post with irrelevant code.

Any ideas how I can get this to work as intended?

```
buttonClickedHandler.js

callbackFn {function(){
    const a = ApiCallA(...) // Returns a promise

    const b = a.then(resA => {
        // Some work done here
        return ApiCallB(…); // Returns a promise

    const c = b.then(resB => {
        // Some work done here
        return ApiCallC(…); // Returns a promise  

    return Promise.all( ([a, b, c] )
        .then( ([resA, resB, resC] ) => {
            // Some work done here
            return ApiCallD
        })
        .then( resD => {
            const intId = setInterval( () => {
                reduxAsyncAction(resD.jobId) // <-- This makes a final API call
                    if (props.jobStatus){ // <-- jobStatus gets updated too late
                         clearInterval(intId ); 
                    }
                }, 5000)
          })
         .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

```
redux action creator

export const reduxAsyncAction= (jobId) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(taskStatusStart()); // <- Basic sync. action creator
        return databaseQuery() // Returns Promise therefore pushed to taskqueue while other function run
        .then(dbData=>{
            const completionStatus = dbData.status; // <- True or False
            dispatch(taskStatusSuccess(completionStatus)) // <- Basic sync. action creator
        },
        error => {
            dispatch(taskStatusFail(error)); // <- Basic sync. action creator
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs of reactjs/redux - what I do know is your `reduxAsyncAction` function returns a Promise, which you're not basically ignoring in that setInterval callback

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidUpdate` or `useEffect`

1. These will run whenever `props.jobStatus` updates in your redux store
2. Check for `taskStatusSuccess(completionStatus)` or `taskStatusFail(error)` that you are dispatching from `reduxAsyncAction`
3. `clearinterval(intId)` if the status matches

You will also need to add the `intId` to be within scope by declaring  outside of the `callbackFn` such as:

- `this.intId` in the constructor of a class based component
- `let intId` at the top of the functional component.

Class based components:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    if (intId && props.jobStatus === 'completionStatus' || props.jobStatus === 'error'){
          clearInterval(intId); 
          intId = null;
    } 
}
```

Functional components:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (intId && props.jobStatus === 'completionStatus' || props.jobStatus === 'error'){
        clearInterval(intId); 
        intId = null;
    } 
},[props.jobStatus])
```

Comment: Hi WIlliam. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that still leaves me with the issue of the async redux thunk call not finishing entirely before the if statement is executed.

Comment: i updated my answer to be more clear i believe. let me know if im still missing the mark, cheers!